# Email ID doesn't link to the existing account

Tags: bug, login

I used to log in with my credentials and this **(user:4960619)** was my profile. But today when I tried to login in with the same credentials, it says the email id **does not exist**. It created a completely new account with which I have raised the concern right now.

Comment: The user Id you posted is from which site? Can you link to the user page?

Comment: Is this the one? http://stackoverflow.com/users/4960619/jeet-adhikari

Comment: yeah sure `http://stackoverflow.com/users/4960619/jeet-adhikari` and  `http://stackoverflow.com/users/7478836/jeet-adhikari`

Comment: The credentials on that account are different from the ones you used here (very similar, but *different*).

Comment: is it? actually I made that recently. Is there any way I can know the previous email id?? because I dont see any previous emails from stackoverflow in my gmail account with which i think i logged in.

Comment: I can't provide it, given there is no way to tell that the credentials do belong to the same person. I suggest you use the [contact us](http://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) form and supply identifying information that will allow us to know both are you (for instance, if you gave us your birthday on the other account, that will help confirm, or tell us where you logged on from - IP address and so on).